# How do I add multiple tuples and convert into only list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I got confused between Representations. But I checked, my output is "class tuple"

My code is:

```
for key, value in analysis.items():
    tvi = (key, {k:v for k, v in value.indicators.items() if k in indica})
    TVA = print(tvi)
```

And I had a list of multiple tuples:

```
        ('James',{'hair':'black','eye':'brown'})
        ('Michael',{'hair':'brown','eye':None})
        ('Robert',{'hair':'red','eye':'black'})
        ('Washington',{'hair':'grey','eye':'grey'})
        ('Jefferson',{'hair':'brown','eye':''})
```

I want to convert into a big list like that:

```
[
        ('James',{'hair':'black','eye':'brown'}),
        ('Michael',{'hair':'brown','eye':None}),
        ('Robert',{'hair':'red','eye':'black'}),
        ('Washington',{'hair':'grey','eye':'grey'}),
        ('Jefferson',{'hair':'brown','eye':''})
        ]
```

Comment: Parentheses don't make a tuple, commas do. In your case these are not tuples

Comment: Do you mean you got a list of 1-tuple containing a dict? Please update your question to show that clearly (e.g. show the output of `print(variable)` in the interactive console).  As it is your question is unclear because you have multiple statements in your first code block and a single statement in the second, and the first code block is not a list.

Comment: Sorry. I edited

Comment: Sorry. I coppied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with list comprehension,

```
[(key, {k:v for k, v in value.indicators.items() if k in indica}) 
        for key, value in analysis.items()]
```